# IntelliJ Maven dependency 'org.lwjgl:lwjgl:3.1.5' not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lwjgl

I'm using Maven for a project using LWJGL3 version 3.1.5. I used the pom generator on the LWJGL website and IntelliJ tells me the following on line 4:

> Dependency 'org.lwjgl:lwjgl:3.1.5' not found

This is the problematic part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: which repository is it pulling from? - can you `right-click` on the `pom.xml` and do `maven > reimport` ?

Comment: Reimporing dependencies did the trick. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try re-importing your dependencies.

In IntelliJ, you can `right-click` on the `pom.xml` and do `maven > reimport`

Also, make sure you have access to the repository you are importing from (i.e. internet access, no firewall or 
proxy blocking the repo, etc.)